# Is there any command line tool for decoding GDPR consent string

Tags: command-line

I am looking for a command/online_tool where I could provide the GDPR user consent string and it could return decoded parameters

I installed the package mentioned in https://pypi.org/project/consent-decoder/1.0.1/ but don't know what command to issue

I am using MacOs

Thanks in advance